# menu block with nice menu

Tags: routes

I am using the [Menu Block](http://drupal.org/project/menu_block) module and the [Nice Menus](http://drupal.org/project/nice_menus) module. In my theme's left sidebar I have a block with that menu block (2nd level). How to use a Nice Menu in that region? If I put that Nice Menu, I get 1st level menu, but I need 2nd level menu from Menu Block module who create me 2nd level +

Answer (score 1):

In the block configuration, you should be able to choose which menu it uses.

Comment: It uses Menu block 2nd level menu. I want to use Nice menu, but not 1st level...

Comment: ah i see, you probably need to hook something from that module .., you could also try to setup another menu you'll use as base for the block